# Unix cut command taking an unordered list as arguments

Tags: unix, shell

The Unix `cut` command takes a list of fields, but not the order that I need it in.

```
$ echo 1,2,3,4,5,6 | cut -d, -f 1,2,3,5
1,2,3,5

$ echo 1,2,3,4,5,6 | cut -d, -f 1,3,2,5
1,2,3,5
```

However, I would like a Unix shell command that will give me the fields **in the order that I specify.**

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
pax> echo 1,2,3,4,5,6 | awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","}{print $1,$3,$2,$5}'
1,3,2,5
```

or:

```
pax> echo 1,2,3,4,5,6 | awk -F, -vOFS=, '{print $1,$3,$2,$5}'
1,3,2,5
```

Answer (score 2):

Or just use the shell

```
$ set -f
$ string="1,2,3,4,5"
$ IFS=","
$ set -- $string
$ echo $1 $3 $2 $5
1 3 2 5
```

Comment: @ghostdog74: You need to do `set -f` first, otherwise globbing will happen if the string contains `*` or `?` or `[`. And even then, some shells may interprete `\\`; I'm not sure what POSIX says about this, and shell authors seem divided on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Awk based solution is elegant. Here is a perl based solution:

```
echo 1,2,3,4,5,6 | perl -e '@order=(1,3,2,5);@a=split/,/,<>;for(@order){print $a[$_-1];}'
```

Comment: with later Perl, there's the -F option :)